# Rupee symbol not appearing in Internet explorer only

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I am using default rupee symbol configured via magento currency setup. Most of the browsers it is working fine except internet explorer. In i.e. below is what is shown instead of symbol.
[image: Rupee Symbol not displayed screenshot]

Comment: What is the **text encoding** of your website and of your browser ? Does changing it resolve the problem ?

Comment: Which versions of Internet Explorer?

Comment: Internet explorer version 11 in windows 7

Comment: check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599482/rupee-symbol-not-working-in-internet-explorer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598085/displaying-the-indian-currency-symbol-on-a-website. How can i use font awesome in magento? How can I replace the current currency symbol with <i class="fa fa-inr"></i>